# Any open dataset for Geopolitical queries and answers?

Tags: data-request, big-data, unstructured-data

I'm searching for queries/questions and answers that can be run and tested on top of the ICEWS and GDELT dataset, so that I could detect whether the query inference engine returns all the expected answers using F1 or precision/recall curves.